# How to do aggregation sort in mongodb inner object with c#

Tags: c#, mongodb, c#-4.0, aggregation-framework, mongodb-.net-driver

I need to sort inner object sort of a class with mongo db. i need to sort based on marks

**Sample Json:**

```
{"_id":"58e46f81c4734559ac8082f0","Name":"test","Students":[{"Name":"A","Marks":"988"}]}
{"_id":"58e46f81c4734559ac8082f1","Name":"sahir","Students":[{"Name":"sahir","Marks":"311"}]}
```

Here is the class:

```
public class  Student
    {


        [BsonId]
        public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    
        [BsonElement]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        
        public ICollection <Students> Students { get; set; }

    }

    public class Students
    {
    
        public string Name { get; set; }
        
        public string Marks{ get; set; }

    }
```

**Action**

```
public IActionResult Index()
    {


        //Get the database connection
        mongoDatabase = GetMongoDatabase();
        var x = mongoDatabase.GetCollection<Student>("student").Find(FilterDefinition<Student>.Empty).ToList();


  
        var _dbContext = mongoDatabase.GetCollection<Student>("student");

// mongo db document collection student class students objects need to sort based on marks.
        _dbContext.Aggregate<Student>()
                         .Sort(x=> x.students.marks).Skip((page-1)*pageSize).Limit(100);
                          
                          .ToList();         -- how to do that sort in this line 


or 


    var result = _dbContext.Aggregate<Student>().Sort(new BsonDocument("Marks", 1)).ToList();



        return View(result);
    }
```

**Note:**

`Don't provide linq Solution to convert asQuerable operators to do LINQ queries. This question is only based on an understanding of MongoDB aggregation sort and how to use that in C#`.

No forum has any reference for internal objects sorting with c#.There are lots of examples of C# mongodb sorting without aggragtion

**Problem:**
I have aggregation sort mongo shell query .. don't know to implement that in c#

Answer (score 2):

are you trying to get a list of all students sorted by their marks? if so, try this:

```cs
var students = await collection.AsQueryable()
    .SelectMany(c => c.Students)
    .OrderBy(s => s.Marks)
    .Skip(50)
    .Take(10)
    .ToListAsync();
```

the easiest way to get the result you want is via the `AsQueryable()` interface.

if you must use the `Aggregate()` api, you can do the following:

```cs
var students = await collection.Aggregate()
    .Unwind(c => c.Students)
    .ReplaceWith<BsonDocument>("$Students")
    .Sort("{Marks:1}")
    .Skip(0)
    .Limit(10)
    .As<Student>()
    .ToListAsync();
```

test program:

```js
using MongoDB.Driver;
using MongoDB.Driver.Linq;
using MongoDB.Entities;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestApplication
{
    public class Course : Entity
    {
        public IEnumerable<Student> Students { get; set; }
    }

    public class Student
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Marks { get; set; }
    }

    public static class Program
    {
        private static async Task Main()
        {
            await DB.InitAsync("test");

            await new[] {
                new Course
                {
                    Students = new[] {
                        new Student { Name = "a", Marks = "100"},
                        new Student { Name = "b", Marks = "200"},
                    }
                },
                new Course
                {
                    Students = new[] {
                        new Student { Name = "d", Marks = "400"},
                        new Student { Name = "c", Marks = "300"},
                    }
                }
            }.SaveAsync();

        var students = await DB.Queryable<Course>()
            .SelectMany(c => c.Students)
            .OrderBy(s => s.Marks)
            .Skip(50)
            .Take(10)
            .ToListAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No i had  already with linq to convert asquerable in memory collection and i don't want to use linq , need to use sort aggreation framework, because our framework designed based on that , and done filter, sort if dont have nested object working fine. but when inside nested have problem.

Comment: AsQueryable is done server-side, not in memory... but ok :-)

Comment: sorry i confused with ienumerable and asquereable. If it done serverside MongoDB don't have that operator I convert that collection to list and then i convert Linq asQuerable to do that operation , if i do that our base framework won't allow it. so i forced to use the aggregation framework..AsQueryable() filters in the SQL Server level and fetches the whatever record needed. So, it reduces the memory requirement and improves the performance of an application.

Comment: see my updated answer. the `AsQueryable()` endpoint doesn't do any filtering in memory. it just converts your LINQ instructions to mongo query language and sends that to the db server. so all you get back from the mongo server is the exact items you asked for.

Comment: that i know  and i have already filtering with mongodb thats working fine only problem happen in Sort and have prepared this query I don't want to translate that query with LINQ translation. is there any other way to do with aggregation operators .`dbContext.Aggregate<Student>().unwind(x=>x.students).Sort(new BsonDocument("Marks", 1)).Skip((page-1)*pageSize).Limit(100).ToList();`

Comment: added the aggregate method. but it's uglier than linq :-)

Comment: Thanks .. let me check and update because our base framework returns format is different. so if i use an aggregate framework its easy to handle. and what you think asqueryable is better than this, because i am new to mongodb with C#.

Comment: what is the expected output type? `List<Student>`? both of the above queries targets the same mongodb aggregation framework. the performance difference will be negligable. the reason to use AsQueryable is because it's strongly-typed and easy to read/understand.

Comment: In this example I have provided a sample scenario as Student, Yes Base class Student is the output type if I need to change as queryable need to do change in so many places and base framework .if i want to touch the base framework , requires some permisson .. thanks for valuable answers. let me chech and upvote your answers

Comment: `AsQueryable` is just the starting point. it is not the return type. the `.ToListAsync()` method at the end is what actually executes the query and gets the results from the db. until that point, you're just building a query. if you don't call `.ToListAsync()`, then nothing happens with the db.

Comment: While using the above aggregate fluent api `FormatException: Element 'Marks' does not match any field or property of class AspNetCoreMVCMongoDBDemo.Models.Student.
MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMapSerializer.DeserializeClass(BsonDeserializationContext context)` But Student Class have Students objects